# Matricies Problem

Tags: matrices

What $3 \times 3$ matrix has the effect of these steps, in this order?

Subtract row $1$ from row $2$,

Add row $1$ to row $2$,

Add row $2$ from row $3$,

Subtract half of row $3$ from row $1$,

I have no idea how to solve a question in this form, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You left out the second row number in the first three operations.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** A matrix that accomplishes the first operation is $$\pmatrix{
1 &0 &0\\
-1 &1 &0\\
0&0&1
}
$$
If you don't see why, multiply a general $3\times 3$ matrix on the left by this matrix.
Now you should be able to come up with the matrices for the other operations.

Do you see how to combine them?  What would be the result of performing all those operations on a matrix?  How can you express it with a single matrix?

Comment: so I got {(-1,-1/2,0),(-1,1,0),(0,1,0)} is that right?

Comment: Is that right? I can post my steps if needed.

Comment: @user9501082 Yes, if you'd like me to check it, please post your steps.

Answer (score 1):

Let your $3\times 3$ matrix be $$
    A=\begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    a & b & c \\
    k & m & n \\
    \end{pmatrix}\\
$$ So now, we need to do some row operations:$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    a & b & c \\
    k & m & n \\
    \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{r_2\rightarrow r_2-r_1}\begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    a-x & b-y & c-z \\
    k & m & n \\
    \end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{r_2\rightarrow r_1+r_2} \begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    a & b & c \\
    k & m & n \\
    \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{r_3\rightarrow r_2+r_3}\begin{pmatrix}
    x & y & z \\
    a & b & c \\
   a+ k & b+m &c+ n \\
    \end{pmatrix}\xrightarrow{r_1\rightarrow r_1-\frac{r_3} 2}\begin{pmatrix}
    x-\frac{a+k}2 & y-\frac{b+m}2 & z-\frac{c+n}2 \\
    a & b & c \\
   a+ k & b+m &c+ n \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: So given what saulspatz posted would this be the answer:{(-1,-1/2,0),(-1,1,0),(0,1,0)}

Comment: @saulspatz only mentioned about first operation

Comment: This is the result of the 4 operations.  (I haven't checked, but I assume it's correct.)  I don't think that's what the question is asking for, though.  I think it asks for a matrix M such that MA will be the matrix you have written.

Comment: Oh, I see you are right@saulspatz